# Jetpack compose thousands separator visual transformation that also works with a decimal

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How to implement a thousands separator visual transformation which also works with decimals too. I have found an implementation of thousand separator visual transformation for Int numbers but the problem is when I want to use it for decimal numbers which I have to control the count of decimal separator not to exceed more than 1 time.

[Implementation link](https://github.com/adibfara/Compose-TextField-Thousands-Separator/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/snakydesign/composetextview/ui/PriceFilter.kt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- **`onValueChange`** attribute to restrict the allowed character to a decimal number using a regex pattern
- **`visualTransformation`** to format the number with the thousands separators

Something like:

```
val pattern = remember { Regex("^\\d*\\.?\\d*\$") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal),
    visualTransformation = ThousandSeparatorTransformation()
)

class ThousandSeparatorTransformation : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {

        val symbols = DecimalFormat().decimalFormatSymbols
        val decimalSeparator = symbols.decimalSeparator

        var outputText = ""
        var integerPart = 0L
        var decimalPart = ""

        if (text.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            val number = text.text.toDouble()
            integerPart = number.toLong()
            outputText += NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(integerPart)
            if (text.text.contains(decimalSeparator)) {
                decimalPart = text.text.substring(text.text.indexOf(decimalSeparator))
                if (decimalPart.isNotEmpty()) {
                    outputText += decimalPart
                }
            }
        }

        val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
            override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                return outputText.length
            }

            override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                return text.length
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(
            text = AnnotatedString(outputText),
            offsetMapping = numberOffsetTranslator
        )
    }
}
```

With this `OffsetMapping` the cursor remains stationary at the end of the value. Otherwise you have to calculate the thousandsSeparatorCount and fix the offset according to it.

[image]

Comment: This method disables manual cursor selection. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Seems to be a bug on Compose https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240220202 fixed in 1.3.0-beta01

Comment: @geft It is an expected result. As explained in the answer: With this OffsetMapping the cursor remains stationary at the end of the value. Otherwise you have to calculate the thousandsSeparatorCount and fix the offset according to it.

Comment: Got it, For future reference, this is the code snippet if you want to enable cursor dragging. Just minus it for the inverse.

`offset + countThousandSeparators(outputText.take(offset + 1))`

Comment: @geft could you please provide the full code that enables cursor dragging?

Comment: @geft for moveable cursor you check CurrencyoffsetMapping here
https://proandroiddev.com/editing-currency-textfields-in-jetpack-compose-b7074b4682ea

Answer (score 5):

Decimal Amount Visual Transformation - Jetpack compose Visual Transformation for decimal input. **Cursor works well!**

**DecimalAmountTransformation**

```
private val groupingSymbol = ' '
private val decimalSymbol = '.'

private val numberFormatter: DecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###").apply {
    decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).apply {
        groupingSeparator = groupingSymbol
        decimalSeparator = decimalSymbol
    }
}

class DecimalAmountTransformation : VisualTransformation {

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val transformation = reformat(text.text)

        return TransformedText(
            AnnotatedString(transformation.formatted ?: ""),
            object : OffsetMapping {
                override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                    return transformation.originalToTransformed[offset]
                }

                override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                    return transformation.transformedToOriginal[offset]
                }
            },
        )
    }

    private fun reformat(original: String): Transformation {
        val parts = original.split(decimalSymbol)
        check(parts.size < 3) { "original text must have only one dot (use filteredDecimalText)" }

        val hasEndDot = original.endsWith('.')
        var formatted = original

        Log.d("original_tag", original)

        if (original.isNotEmpty() && parts.size == 1) {
            formatted = numberFormatter.format(BigDecimal(parts[0]))

            if (hasEndDot) {
                formatted += decimalSymbol
            }
        } else if (parts.size == 2) {
            val numberPart = numberFormatter.format(BigDecimal(parts[0]))
            val decimalPart = parts[1]

            formatted = "$numberPart.$decimalPart"
        }

        val originalToTransformed = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val transformedToOriginal = mutableListOf<Int>()
        var specialCharsCount = 0

        formatted.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
            if (groupingSymbol == char) {
                specialCharsCount++
            } else {
                originalToTransformed.add(index)
            }
            transformedToOriginal.add(index - specialCharsCount)
        }
        originalToTransformed.add(originalToTransformed.maxOrNull()?.plus(1) ?: 0)
        transformedToOriginal.add(transformedToOriginal.maxOrNull()?.plus(1) ?: 0)

        return Transformation(formatted, originalToTransformed, transformedToOriginal)
    }
}


data class Transformation(
    val formatted: String?,
    val originalToTransformed: List<Int>,
    val transformedToOriginal: List<Int>,
)
```

We need to filter input as well to achive the needed result
**DecimalnputFilter.kt**

```
private val decimalSymbol = '.'

object InputFilterRegex {
    val DecimalInput by lazy { Regex("^(\\d*\\.?)+\$") }
}


fun filteredDecimalText(input: TextFieldValue): TextFieldValue {
    var inputText = input.text.replaceFirst(regex = Regex("^0+(?!$)"), "")
    var startsWithDot = input.text.startsWith(decimalSymbol)

    var selectionStart = input.selection.start
    var selectionEnd = input.selection.end

    if (startsWithDot) {
        inputText = "0$inputText"

        if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
            selectionStart++
            selectionEnd++
        } else {
            selectionEnd++
        }
    }

    val parts = inputText.split(decimalSymbol)
    var text = if (parts.size > 1) {
        parts[0] + decimalSymbol + parts.subList(1, parts.size).joinToString("")
    } else {
        parts.joinToString("")
    }

    if (text.startsWith(decimalSymbol)) {
        text = "0$text"
    }

    return input.copy(text = text, selection = TextRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd))
}
```

Finally, usage will look like this:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = {
        if (!it.text.contains(InputFilterRegex.DecimalInput)) {
            return@BasicTextField
        }
        onValueChange(filteredDecimalText(it))
    },
    visualTransformation = DecimalAmountTransformation(),
)
```

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/Islomov49/b0fbfd86d4843ef99c5c961e5de04c18)

Comment: What is Transformation class ?

Comment: @DaniilPozdnyakov Hi, yes my bad. I've updated the answer and gist. It is just data class which keeps needed data inside

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, cursor works fine, no casting, no regex and no too much data stored for each transformation, you also can config how the separation behave.
Test and preview can see [gist](https://gist.github.com/fyam1997/503e0d78cf50e58679883ac347fad09a)

```kotlin
internal val VisualTransformation.Companion.ThousandSeparator
    @Composable
    get() = remember(::ThousandSeparatorTransform)

private class ThousandSeparatorTransform : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val symbols = DecimalFormat().decimalFormatSymbols
        val string = text.text

        val integer = string.substringBefore(symbols.decimalSeparator)
        val decimals = string.replaceFirst(integer, "")

        val integerWithSeparator = integer.withSeparator(symbols.groupingSeparator)
        val output = "$integerWithSeparator$decimals"

        return TransformedText(
            text = AnnotatedString(output),
            offsetMapping = SeparatorMapping(integer),
        )
    }
}

private fun String.withSeparator(
    separator: Char,
    segmentSize: Int = 3,
    startOffset: Int = lastIndex % segmentSize + 1,
    separatorCount: Int = lastIndex / segmentSize,
) = buildString {
    append(this@withSeparator)
    repeat(separatorCount) { index ->
        val offset = startOffset + index * (segmentSize + 1)
        insert(offset, separator)
    }
}

private class SeparatorMapping(
    private val text: String,
    private val segmentSize: Int = 3,
    startOffset: Int = text.lastIndex % segmentSize + 1,
    separatorCount: Int = text.lastIndex / segmentSize,
) : OffsetMapping {
    // 1234 -> xx1,234, padding = xx.length
    private val padding = segmentSize - startOffset
    private val transformedTextLength = text.length + separatorCount

    override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
        val intOffset = offset.coerceAtMost(text.length)
        val offsetSeparatorCount = (intOffset + padding - 1) / segmentSize
        val decimalOffset = (offset - text.length).coerceAtLeast(0)
        return intOffset + offsetSeparatorCount + decimalOffset
    }

    override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
        val intOffset = offset.coerceAtMost(transformedTextLength)
        val offsetSeparatorCount = (intOffset + padding) / (segmentSize + 1)
        val decimalOffset = (offset - transformedTextLength).coerceAtLeast(0)
        return intOffset - offsetSeparatorCount + decimalOffset
    }
}
```